# Why do I get freeze on on FindAll line

Tags: c#, flash, ui-automation, findall

I am trying to UIAutomate a FlashSite.

But code "freezes" i.e. control never returns to me and there is no error on the ***findall*** line.

What might I be doing wrong?

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Automation;


namespace WebFinger
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Process[] firefoxes = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
            Process firefox = firefoxes[0];
            AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(firefox.MainWindowHandle);
            if (rootElement == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hmm");
            }

           foreach (AutomationElement element in rootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here: " + element.Current.ToString());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The scope of the search is relative to the element on which the method
> is called. Elements are returned in the order in which they were
> encountered in the tree.
>
> *When searching for top-level windows on the desktop, **be sure to specify Children in scope, not Descendants**. A search through the
> entire subtree of the desktop could iterate through thousands of items
> and lead to a stack overflow.*
>
> If your client application might try
> to find elements in its own user interface, you must make all UI
> Automation calls on a separate thread.

Comment: @renuiz OK. I changed to Children, now it no-longer freezes but never goes inside the foreach loop. i.e. it is not returning a collection. I tried different controlTypes but none yield a collection.

Comment: That's another topic and I cant help you further because I never did something like that.

Comment: The reason you are finding nothing on the child level of the desktop is because you are searching for `new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button)`. You need to change your property condition to look for the window your button is in get the window's automation element back then repeat the process of looking for the button.